# Using testing.T as anonymous struct field: "too many arguments in call to this.T.common.Fail"

Tags: unit-testing, struct, go

I am trying to solve the [Karate Chop](http://codekata.com/kata/kata02-karate-chop/) kata in Go as an exercise and stuck with this compiler error from my test case:

> too many arguments in call to this.T.common.Fail

I wrapped `testing.T` into a struct with additional methods, as an anonymous struct field:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"
)

type assertions struct {
    *testing.T
}
func (this assertions) assert_equal(expected int, actual int) {
    if (expected != actual) {
        this.Fail(fmt.Sprintf("Failed asserting that %v is %v", actual, expected));
    }
}

func TestChop(t *testing.T) {
  test := assertions{t}

  test.assert_equal(-1, Chop(3, []int{}))
  test.assert_equal(-1, Chop(3, []int{1}))
  ...
}
```

I expect `this.Fail` to call `Fail()` on the anonymous `testing.T` struct field, which takes a string parameter. Why isn't this the case and where does `this.T.common.Fail` come from? I cannot find any reference to `common` in the `testing` package documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [Source file src/testing/testing.go](http://golang.org/src/testing/testing.go)
>
> ```
> // Fail marks the function as having failed but continues execution.
> func (c *common) Fail() {
>   c.mu.Lock()
>   defer c.mu.Unlock()
>   c.failed = true
> }
>
> // common holds the elements common between T and B and
> // captures common methods such as Errorf.
> type common struct {
>   mu       sync.RWMutex // guards output and failed
>   output   []byte       // Output generated by test or benchmark.
>   failed   bool         // Test or benchmark has failed.
>   skipped  bool         // Test of benchmark has been skipped.
>   finished bool
>
>   start    time.Time // Time test or benchmark started
>   duration time.Duration
>   self     interface{}      // To be sent on signal channel when done.
>   signal   chan interface{} // Output for serial tests.
> }
>
> // T is a type passed to Test functions to manage test state and support formatted test logs.
> // Logs are accumulated during execution and dumped to standard error when done.
> type T struct {
>   common
>   name          string    // Name of test.
>   startParallel chan bool // Parallel tests will wait on this.
> }
> ```
>
> [func (*T) Fail](http://golang.org/pkg/testing/#T.Fail)
>
> ```
> func (c *T) Fail()
> ```
>
> Fail marks the function as having failed but continues execution.

There are no arguments to `T.common.Fail()`.

Try `Errorf`:

> [func (*T) Errorf](http://golang.org/pkg/testing/#T.Errorf)
>
> ```
> func (c *T) Errorf(format string, args ...interface{})
> ```
>
> Errorf is equivalent to Logf followed by Fail.

For example,

```
this.Errorf("Failed asserting that %v is %v", actual, expected)
```

Comment: Thanks! This explains both, my stupid mistake and the origin of `T.common`. Of course, `Errorf` was the method I wanted.